# Replacing .loc method of pandas

Tags: pandas

When I try this statement, I get an error...

```
spy_daily.loc[fomc_events.index, "FOMC"] = spy_daily.loc[fomc_events.index, "days_since_fomc"]

KeyError: "Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing labels is no longer supported. The following labels were missing: DatetimeIndex(['2020-03-15', '2008-03-16'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Date', freq=None).
```

Not sure how to correct it. The complete code is available here...

https://www.wrighters.io/analyzing-stock-data-events-with-pandas/

Comment: Did you try `fomc_events.index.tolist()` instead of `fomc_events.index`?

Comment: Isn't it the expected behavior as there are two dates that are not in the daily stock returns when a FOMC meeting as explained just before and after the title/paragraph "The missing dates" in the article you referenced ?

Comment: Author of the above article here. Yes, this KeyError is expected. Those two dates are missing because they are on the weekend and are missing from the daily data. The solution to addressing this is in the article.

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert your index from your other dataframe to a list to subsetting your first dataframe:

```
rows = fomc_events.index.tolist()
spy_daily.loc[rows, "FOMC"] = spy_daily.loc[rows, "days_since_fomc"]
```

Comment: getting the same error.

Comment: How to reproduce your code without APIKEY?